# Как присвоить новый 'ID' в базе

Tags: c#, access, mdb

Есть большая база MS ACCESS у которой создатель решил поставить во всех таблицах тип поля 'ID' как числовой, изменить нельзя т.к. много связей с другими таблицами. Нужно чтобы программа присваивала новым записям 'ID' по порядку в базе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Акцесс умеет в автоинкремент.

То, что когда-то было сделано неправильно - это не повод ещё больше городить костылей - это повод постепенно их исправлять.

Если нужно найти максимальный ID - ну окей, делайте `select max(id) from tablename`, только надо понимать, что при нагруженной базе будут проблемы и тогда - только вернуться к нормальному автоинкременту.

Comment: Насчет "select max(id) from tablename' огромное спасибо. Я говорил, что нельзя исправить под автоинкремент, потому-что в базе много связанных таблиц, плюс программа создается для другой программы(как не странно), и исходника на первую нет, как раз она и неправильно создает, так что приходится вот так выкручиваться.